# Wolfram Mathematica: Dynamic which track only one variable

Tags: dynamic, wolfram-mathematica

I want this:

```
arr[[n]] = b;
```

automatically reevaluate only if **b** changed.

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  You can consider asking your next question at a dedicated Mathematica-site which has the same format:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/   Regarding the question: You need the `TrackedSymbols` option, but note that it will only re-evaluate *if the expression it evaluates to is visible in the notebook*.

Comment: Also, please try to post a minimal and fully functional piece of code showing your problem.

Comment: @Szabolcs you can actually dynamically update expressions without those expressions being visible by using `NotebookDynamicExpression` or its relatives

Answer (score 0):

you probably want

```
 myArray={{1,2},{3,Dynamic[b]}};
```

Check by evaluating `myArray`
and putting also, e.g. `Slider[Dynamic[b],{0,10}]`.

You may set the `Dynamic` part later, i.e. `myArray[[2,2]]=Dynamic[b]` works as well.